# Getting Error : Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Tags: java

I have wrote a piece of code for returning image whenever I hit the url with specific image name, and if image not found just return the error image.

```
@GET
@Path("/getImage/{param1}")
@Produces({ "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/jpg" })
public Response getProductimage(@PathParam("param1") String recievedData) {


    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File("C:/Users/Gaurav/Desktop/AppData/"
                + recievedData);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        file = new File("C:/Users/Gaurav/Desktop/AppData/error.png");

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return Response.ok(file).build();

}
```

Still I'm getting this error when trying to hit for wrong image

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] in context with path [/WebServices] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\AppData\average11.png (The system cannot find the file specified)] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\AppData\average.png15 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:115)
```

Whats wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `new File("X:/non/existing/file")` will *not* throw any exception, so your `catch` block will never be executed.

You should [use `.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) to check whether the file exists, or better, [`.canRead()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead()) to check if you can really read it.

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Gaurav/Desktop/AppData", recievedData);
if (!file.canRead()) {
    file = new File("C:/Users/Gaurav/Desktop/AppData/error.png");
}
return Response.ok(file).build();
```